# Получить данные из ячейки DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, datatable

Путем парсинга считываю данные из таблицы excel в datatable, затем уже выставляю в DataGridView, есть ячейки в которых две-три строки, необходимо вытащить их по отдельности.[image: Вывод текста из ячейки в MessageBox]

На картинке вывод ячейки с помощью MessageBox

Comment: У вас данные в DataTable, вот с ним и работайте. Вопрос в том, как расщепить строки? [String.Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Приведите пример текста из ячейки, в которой несколько строк. Скорее всего, нужно закидывать текст из этой ячейки в переменную String, и делить ее через split().

Comment: @АмирЗакиров смотрите, после правки

Comment: Попробуйте разделить по символу новой строки.
`string s = "some text"; string[] Col = s.Split('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < Col.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Col[i]);
            }`

Comment: @АмирЗакиров - верно, только вместо `\n` следует использовать [Environment.NewLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @АмирЗакиров напишите в ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = "some text"; 
string[] Col = s.Split(Environment.NewLine); 
for (int i = 0; i < Col.Length; i++)  
    Console.WriteLine(Col[i]);
```